# The New Google Takeout

Tags: search, history, privacy

Is there a way to include one's search history within Google Takeout?
https://www.google.com/takeout/

Takeout purports to let you download everything stored within your Google account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, no.  It's an obvious and mysterious gap in service.

You can download your *recent* google searches via an rss feed.
https://www.google.com/history/?output=rss

You can add commands to the url.  The max query is 1000.   num is number of searches and start is how many back to draw from.  Like so:

https://www.google.com/history/?output=rss&num=1000&start=4000

Unfortunately, it starts to become somewhat reduced (as in not actually all of your searches) after a few thousand.  I have over 40,000 searches on google, but I can only go back 7000 on this rss feed.  Bummer. This means we still don´t have access to all our data that they have.

Please prove me wrong!

Comment: It may be perfectly intentional, rather than just a gap. What would be more disquieting is if Google continued to store a user's search history after that user deleted it, doubly so if it remained associated with that user (but for many people the history will be  associated with the user from the queries themselves).

Answer (score 0):

Today is the last day to delete your search history, as suggested by the EFF(https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2012/02/how-remove-your-google-search-history-googles-new-privacy-policy-takes-effect), before the new google terms come into force, linking that history with all the other google products. So if you can't grab it today, delete it so as to partially anonymise it eventually, or be tentacularised.